# Find the image of the set under mapping

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $S = \{(x, y) | 1 \le x \le 2, 2 \le y \le 3\}$ and let $(u, v) = F(x, y) = (xy, y)$. Find the image of $S$ under the mapping of $F$.

This is basically a square with vertices $(1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2)$.

Letting $x = k \implies v = \frac{1}{k} \cdot u$. So basically, a vertical line with $x = k$ has that transformation in the $uv$ plane.

Letting $y = l$, this is confusing. This gives $(u, v) = (x \cdot l, l)$, which I'm not sure how to proceed with. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you are looking for is: $F(S) {~=~ \{(xy, y)\mid 1\leq x\leq 2, 2\leq y\leq 3\} \\ ~=~ \{(z,y)\mid\boxed{{y}}\leq z\leq\boxed{{2y}}, 2\leq y\leq 3\}\\ ~=~ \{(u,v)\mid\boxed{{v}}\leq u\leq\boxed{{2v}}, 2\leq v\leq 3\} \\~=~\{(u,v)\mid 2\leq v \leq u\leq 2v\leq 6\}}$

Fill in the boxes.

Edit: You got it.

Comment: We are supposed to use $u, v$ I assume you mean $y$ is $v$ and $z$ is $u$? If you tell me this, I'll try to fill the box!

Comment: It is just an alpha-substitution away.  @Bana

Comment: Helllo Graham. I am having some doubts and I would appreciate some help. We are supposed to take all of the boundaries correct? I am getting different values on different boundary lines. Consider $x=1, 2 \le y \le 3 \implies 2 \le u \le 3, 2 \le v \le 3$. But now consider $x  = 2, 2 \le y \le 3 \implies 4 \le u \le 6, 2 \le v \le 3$. What do we do in this case?

Comment: bump, would appreciate some assistance :)

Comment: Also, what about the horizontal edges, ie $y = 3, 1 \le x \le 2$?

Comment: Consider that the image of the vertices is $\{(1\cdot2,2), (1\cdot3,3), (2\cdot 2,2),(2\cdot 3,3)\}$.  These are not vertices for a rectangle!  The image is a rhombus.  So the range of $u$ will be dependent on the value of $v$.

Comment: @Bana $y=3, 1\leq x\leq 2 \implies 3\leq 3x\leq 6 \\ y=2, 1\leq x\leq 2 \implies 2\leq 2x\leq 4 \\ y=v, 1\leq x\leq 2 \implies ?\leq vx\leq ?$ etc.

Comment: Yep, I have gotten for these cases:

$y = 3, 1 \le x \le 2 \implies 3 \le u \le 6, v = 3$

$y = 2, 1 \le x \le 2 \implies 2 \le u \le 4, v = 2$

So its apparant with $y$ fixed (hence $v$ fixed) that $v \le u \le 2v$.

But I am still understand about this case:


$x = 1, 2 \le y \le 3 \implies 2 \le u \le 3, 2 \le v \le 3$. How do I put this in a simpler form that makes the other 2 cases valid?

Comment: What about instead of fixing $y$ we fixed $x$? Thats the trouble I'm getting. Otherwise I can see $v \le u \le 2v$.

Comment: You don't fix $x$.  You "fix" $y$ because $v=y$, so they have the same range.  However, $u=xy=xv$ so its range will be dependent on $v$, and in fact $v\leq u\leq 2v$.  So there is your answer $\{(u,v): v\leq u\leq 2v, 2\leq v\leq 3\}$ is the support.

Comment: makes sense sir

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I came up with. Unsure if it is the correct way.

Since it is given that $1 \leq x \leq 2$ and $2 \leq y \leq 3$, we can use these inequalities used in the definition of the set to find the image set.

Since, $x, y > 0$, we can multiply the inequalities without their signs changing.

Therefore, we will have,

$2 \leq xy \leq 6$

Therefore, the image set, say S', will be $S' := \left\lbrace \left( u, v \right) \in \mathbb{R}^2| 2 \leq u \leq 6, 2 \leq v \leq 3 \right\rbrace$

Comment: The image is not a rectangle. Consider, when $y$ has value of $v$ what values can $xy$ take if $1\leq x\leq 2$?